# Aggregate function on aggregated column

Tags: sql

I'm trying this query to get results like in the table below.

```
Select Building, (Total_SRs/Select(SUM(Total_SRs)) From Serveu) As '%age'
From (Select Building, Count(Building) as Total_SRs From serveu Group by Building)

Building            Total_SRs   %age
Abbey Crescent 1    83          4.36%
Abbey Crescent 2    68          3.57%
Barton House 1      12          0.63%
Botton House 1      11          0.58%
Botton House 2       3          0.16%
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?  Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please avoid to include links to photos either your questions or answers, because it makes difficult to the readers of your post to switch back and forth to the photos.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this using ANSI standard window functions:

```
Select Building, Count(*) as Total_SRs,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
From serveu
Group by Building;
```

The `* 1.0` is because some databases do integer division.

I prefer a ratio between 0 and 1.  If you want to format the value as a string, that depends on the database you are using.